# K&R Exercise 1-20: tabs to spaces

Tags: c, strings

I'm learning C with K&R 2<sup>nd</sup> Ed. I've just completed the exercise 1-20 and I would know if my code is correct (i.e. answering the question) and if my style is not too bad. Or just some feebacks to improve myself!

> K&R Exercise 1-20 p.34
>
> Write a program detab that replaces tabs in the input with the proper number  * of blanks to space to the next tab stop.  Assume a fixed set of tab stops, say every n
>   columns.  Should n be a variable or a symbolic parameter?

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178201/kr-exercise-1-20-need-some-clarification)

I put '-' because it's more readable than ' '. But you can totally change it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define COLUMN 8

int main()
{
    int c, i, nc;
    nc = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c != '\t' && c != '\n')
            nc = (nc + 1) % COLUMN;

        if (c == '\n')
            nc = 0;

        if (c == '\t') {
            for (i=1; i<=(COLUMN - nc); ++i) {
                putchar('-');
            }
            nc = 0;
        }
        else
            putchar(c);
    }

return(0);
}
```

Comment: I think K&R style would put the `{` on the same line as the `while`. Also, K&R doesn't put parentheses around a `return` value. And `return` should have four spaces in front of it, like the rest of your `main` function.

Comment: AFAIR they dropped parantheses for `return` statement in second edition. There is really no need for them.

Comment: K&R would also do `i = 1; i <= (`..., rather than without spaces like you wrote it. All of this only applies if you want to write K&R style, rather than something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternate algorithm:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    switch (c) {/* switch instead of if-else... */
    case '\n':
        nc = 0;
        putchar(c);
        break;
    case '\t':
        for (i = COLUMN - nc % COLUMN, nc += i; i > 0; --i) {
            putchar('-');
        }
        break;
    default:
        ++nc; /* increment is faster than increment plus divide */
        putchar(c);
        break;
    }
}
```

`nc` keeps track of the current column position within the line.

Comment: this line: 'for (i = COLUMN - nc % COLUMN, nc += i; i > 0; --i) {' might be a problem, as there is no guarantee in C on the order of evaluation and this line uses a side effect, the result of nc could windup being incorrect.  It is not a good idea to depend on presidence when performing a calculation (use parens)

Comment: @Mahé when the loop starts, `i` is assigned the number of spaced to add. And because the same value needs to be added to `nc`, it is done right there (after comma). Setting `nc` to 0 would also work, but I've decided not to break semantics when `nc` is a position inside the line, not tab offset counter.

Comment: @user3629249 I believe you confuse comma operator and function parameter list evaluation.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk ok thanks, sorry I delete my question because I thought it was stupid, but visibly not, your answer help me!

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk Indeed the if-else is not here very practice because I have to write a third case like : `else if (c != '\t' && c != '\n')`. But I should not know the "switch" structure yet! :)

Thanks for your feedback and `for (i = COLUMN - nc % COLUMN, nc += i; i > 0; --i)` line

Comment: @Mahé You can have `if (c == '\n') { ... } else if (c == '\t') { ...} else { ... } `construct then. Semantically the same.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk But it creates a problem, let's try this code on a second line input :
`while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\n') {
            nc = 0;
            putchar(c);
        }
        if (c == '\t') {
            for (i = COLUMN - nc % COLUMN, nc += i; i > 0; --i) {
                putchar('-');
            }
        }
        else {
            ++nc;
            putchar(c);
        }
    }`

The second line is shifted (because of the first value of i on the second line?)

Comment: @Mahé you missed `else`... It is a case with so-called 'dangling else'. so the actual construct looks like: `if () {} else { if () {} else {}}`  but can be written in a shorter form: `if () {} else if () {} else {}`

Comment: @user3629249 The comma operator acts as a sequence point. It's fine.

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk Oh yes you're totaly right... I think i'm not very comfortable with `if-else` construction yet! Sorry to make you write the same thing twice.